# SignalR installation through the nuget

Tags: nuget, signalr

All articles say that SignalR can be installed from

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

nuget package.

But this package is not available through nuget interface in VisualStudio but only if you install from the console.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

Why?

Also it's not available here http://nuget.org/packages?q=signalr

Can you somebody explain what the right way to install SignalR?

Comment: Console is the way I've installed. Works just fine. Keep in mind it's RC2 (last time I checked)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SignalR is still pre release so you need to install it from the command line with the -pre option.  From what I've heard it should be available in the next RTM update.

Comment: You can also change the filtering options in the GUI to "Include Pre-release"

Answer (score 3):

It is found here in the gallery: http://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.signalr

Use `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR -Pre` to install from the console.

Comment: I saw it but for some unknown reason I ignored "-pre" and didn't ask why is it for...

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Manage Nuget packages UI in VS to install pre-release packages as well
http://docs.nuget.org/docs/release-notes/nuget-2.2 has instructions on how to do it as well